# move the focus from textbox to ajax combobox on enter key

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to move the focus from the textbox to an ajax combobox on enter key

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtGroupSname").keydown(checkForEnter);
        function checkForEnter(event) {

            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                document.getElementById("cmbUnder").focus();
                return false;
                //$("#cmbUnder").focus();
            }
        }
    });
```

txtGroupSname is my textbox and cmbUnder is the ajax combobox.

Any ideas or suggestions please.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (e.which == 9 && isShiftKey == true) {
                if (document.getElementById("cmbUnder_OptionList").focus() == true) {
                    document.getElementById("txtGroupSname").focus();
                    StopDefaultAction(e);
                }
            }
```

Used this code to move from combobox to the above the textbox

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtGroupSname").keydown(
    function checkForEnter(event) {

        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            document.getElementById("cmbUnder").focus();
            return false;
            //$("#cmbUnder").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Try this

Comment: I tried your code but it is not working. I am using ajax combobox <ajax:ComboBox ID="cmbUnder" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" class="text" TabIndex="3" AccessKey="f" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CaseSensitive="False" ItemInsertLocation="OrdinalText" height="16px" width="329px"> </ajax:ComboBox>

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net applications generated clientIds for all elements. Your id in html if your controls client id, and not the id you have on the server.

Make sure you are using the clientId. You may need to emit javascript from asp.net by using a RegisterClientScript method.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this working  [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HFGm3/)  first.

*In this demo, when you hit inside input box, then focus goes onto select box. To make sure that it has happen, try pressing down arrow key from keyboard to choose different options.*

---

Modify your script above, by this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtGroupSname").keydown(function(event) {
      // call checkForEnter function with event as a parameter
      checkForEnter(event);
    });

    function checkForEnter(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            // set focus to select box
            $("#cmbUnder").focus();
            //document.getElementById("cmbUnder").focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code but it is not working. I am using ajax combobox <ajax:ComboBox ID="cmbUnder" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" class="text" TabIndex="3" AccessKey="f"
AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CaseSensitive="False" ItemInsertLocation="OrdinalText" height="16px" width="329px"> 
</ajax:ComboBox>